# Group data by dates in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to group the data by date and each column for a two week period. I wish this to remain static depending on the day I run the query. I.e. if I run it today it will return data for the next two weeks of the current date.

My current query:

```
SELECT

ITT1.Code,

cast(isnull(sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,DueDate)=4 THEN (OWOR.PlannedQty) END),0) as int)  as 'Wed',
cast(isnull(sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,DueDate)=5 THEN (OWOR.PlannedQty) END),0) as int)  as 'Thu',
cast(isnull(sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,DueDate)=6 THEN (OWOR.PlannedQty) END),0) as int) as 'Fri',
cast(isnull(sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,DueDate)=7 THEN (OWOR.PlannedQty) END),0) as int)  as 'Sat',
cast(isnull(sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,DueDate)=8 THEN (OWOR.PlannedQty) END),0) as int)  as 'Sun',
cast(isnull(sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,DueDate)=9 THEN (OWOR.PlannedQty) END),0) as int)  as 'Mon',
cast(isnull(sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,DueDate)=10 THEN (OWOR.PlannedQty) END),0) as int)  as 'Tue',
cast(isnull(sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,DueDate)=11 THEN (OWOR.PlannedQty) END),0) as int)  as 'Wed',
cast(isnull(sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,DueDate)=12 THEN (OWOR.PlannedQty) END),0) as int)  as 'Thu',
cast(isnull(sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,DueDate)=13 THEN (OWOR.PlannedQty) END),0) as int)  as 'Fri',
cast(isnull(sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,DueDate)=14 THEN (OWOR.PlannedQty) END),0) as int)  as 'Sat',
cast(isnull(sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,DueDate)=15 THEN (OWOR.PlannedQty) END),0) as int)  as 'Sun',
cast(isnull(sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,DueDate)=16 THEN (OWOR.PlannedQty) END),0) as int)  as 'Mon',
cast(isnull(sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,DueDate)=17 THEN (OWOR.PlannedQty) END),0) as int)  as 'Tue'
 
FROM OWOR
LEFT JOIN ITT1 ON OWOR.ITEMCODE = ITT1.Father
WHERE DueDate >= GETDATE()-1 AND DueDate <= dateadd(day,15,getdate()) AND OWOR.UserSign = '108' 
GROUP BY ITT1.Code
```

Here is what the above returns, notice how it shows no data in the second week.

| Comp SKU ID | Planned | Completed QTY | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thur | Fri | Sat | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SKU a | 108 | 11 | -18 | -26 | -51 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| SKU b | 1361 | 0 | -808 | 0 | -354 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| SKU c | 6 | 2 | 0 | -1 | -1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |

I've tried to use use datepart but I get two issues from this:

1 - If there's data on the day Mon for two different weeks, it doesn't segregate by the date, but the day. So the second Mon will have no data even knowing it should.

2 - If I run it consecutive days, the data skews. Presumably because I used datepart.

Is there a way I can use the actual date rather than the day, and display it for the next two week's of the system date?

Thanks

Comment: hi kay, it would be better if you could share the table(s) structure, example data, and the origin of those numbers.

Comment: We need a [mre] with emphasis on *minimal* i.e. create a mock example as simple as possible which demonstrates the issue, because as it stands your query in way too complex for us to deal with.

Comment: Hi Both, OK will do this., will upload soon. Thanks.

Comment: HI, i think i've simplified it. Not sure how to get the table structures? The numbers are from table OWOR, the numbers = planned orders and I need it to be grouped by date stamp rather than the "day". As the numbers accumulate.

Comment: `DATEPART(dw,...` (weekday) is always between 1-7. any "matching" outside of this range will never work. it's also a good idea to have column with unique names.

Comment: @GiovanniLuisotto So what would in it's place given my report needs to look two weeks in advance from the current date.

Comment: just grouping by date will work... and when you have the date you can produce whatever "label" you want for your report columns. Given that this is for a report, I expect whatever reporting tool you use to be able to build a pivot table and solve the pivoting there, if that's not the case you can Pivot the data in SQL (there is a PIVOT function). Still, we need usable sample data to help you

Comment: Time to take a step back and consider how this data is used. You have two "Wed" columns. Which actual dates do those correspond to? No one using the output you provided will know - maybe there is a convention (which needs to be expressed in your description)? Are you summing to get actual sums by day or summing as a pivot alternative?